# How to add my style to my plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I used:

```
        wp_register_style("jquery.myplugin-1.0.css", "http://wordpress.loc/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/css" , "jquery.myplugin-1.0.css" , array(), "1.0");
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.myplugin-1.0.css');
```

But it get to

```
http://wordpress.loc/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/css?ver=3.4.2
```

What's possibly wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
wp_register_style("jquery.myplugin-1.0.css", "http://wordpress.loc/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/css/jquery.myplugin-1.0.css");
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.myplugin-1.0.css');
```

But this is better:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.myplugin-1.0.css', plugins_url( '/css/jquery.myplugin-1.0.css' , __FILE__ ));
```

If you register and enqueue at the same time all can be done with [wp_enqueu_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), it has the same arguments.

Second you used your url hardcoded. In my second example the plugin url will be dynamic so it will work on every WordPress without changing the url.

Comment: ok, yes, it works, though, just added the styles, but don't applying them, what can be the reason of it?

Comment: is the url correct? for example if you open that same url in a new tab will it display your style sheet?

Comment: for example I have element `<div id="myelement" />` and a style with `#myelement { background: #000; }`, but nothing happens. Yes, url is very correct now!

Comment: Just inspect it in firebug / chrome webconsole. It probably is overruled somewhere

Comment: I'm tried also `#main .entry-content #myelement { background: #000; }` , still nothing, though all scripts are included well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17282/discussion-between-janw-and-victor-czechov)